# How to avoid conditional formatting change and pivot table columns disappearance when refreshing?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which shows the relation of employees' names and FTEs per month, and I put conditional formatting according the range of the FTE:

1. 0 - 0.85 = light orange
2. 0.86 - 1.14 = solid green
3. greater than 1.14 = red

However, when I refresh the pivot table, some columns disappear, is there a way to solve this with a macro or why do I have this error?

I already have selected the field of keeping format when refreshing in pivot table options, but this is not working.

Comment: "...when I refresh the pivot table, some columns disappear" do you mean to say "when I refresh the pivot table, the conditional formatting of some columns disappears" ?

Comment: Yeah, not only the conditional formatting, also the whole column disappear

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Pivot Table shows only the items for which there is data. To show all the data in a Pivot Field you have to make the following change for each field in which you want to see all the data:

1. Right-click an item in the pivot table field, and click Field Settings;
2. In the Field Settings dialog box, click the Layout & Print
   tab;
3. Check the 'Show items with no data' check box;
4. Click OK.

You can also preserve cell formatting by the following simple actions:

1. Right-click the pivot table and choose PivotTable Options from the
   resulting submenu;
2. Click the Layout & Format tab;
3. At the bottom of the options, check 'Preserve cell formatting on update' and 'Autofit column widths on update';
4. Click OK.